# Xamarin and UWP Secondary Window Sizing

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, xamarin.uwp

I'm using the following code to launch a secondary window.

```
static async Task OpenSecondaryWindow(ContentPage contentPage) {
    var coreApplicationView = CoreApplication.CreateNewView();
    int viewId = 0;
    await coreApplicationView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
        var frame = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Frame();
        frame.Navigate(contentPage);
        Window.Current.Content = frame;
        Window.Current.Activate();
        viewId = ApplicationView.GetForCurrentView().Id;
        App.StyleViews();
    });
    bool viewShown = await ApplicationViewSwitcher.TryShowAsStandaloneAsync(viewId);
}
```

ContentPage is of the same class that's instantiated and set to MainPage in my Xamarin.Forms.Application.

The problem I'm having is that when sizing the secondary window, the frame sizes, but not the content. What do I need to do to get the content to size as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does the trick.

```
frame.SizeChanged += delegate (object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e) {
    contentPage.Layout(new Rectangle(0, 0, e.NewSize.Width, e.NewSize.Height));
};
```